# Confused about bounty points

Tags: support, bounty

Related to [Should an advisor care if their student becomes overweight?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/45903/should-an-advisor-care-if-their-student-becomes-overweight)

How do I figure out whether it was the OP who awarded the bounty, the software, or someone/something else?

What happened to the other 25 points?  (Or am I mistaken in thinking that the minimum bounty is 50?)  I do realize that a bounty can be split between two answers, but I don't see the other 25 anywhere in this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [help center](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) instructions to those who offer a bounty:

> If you do not award the bounty within 24 hours of the bounty period ending, half the bounty value will be automatically awarded to the top voted answer posted after the bounty start, provided it has a score of at least 2. If no new answer matches this requirement, no reputation will be awarded at all, and the reputation used on the bounty will be lost forever.

If the full bounty amount is awarded -> the person who set the bounty awarded it.

If half the bounty amount is awarded -> the software awarded it. The person who offered it did not award it to an answer within the deadline, despite several reminders.

Also see [How does the bounty system work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work).

Comment: Thanks.  I'm still confused, though. It doesn't look, in this case, as though the bounty was awarded to the top-voted question.

Comment: @aparent001 "top voted answer *posted after the bounty start*"

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not getting your meaning.  Is there some technical thing going on here involving some exact timing?

Comment: @aparent001 the highest-voted answer was already there when the bounty was offered. A bounty is only auto-awarded to a *new* answer.

Comment: Weird!  ---  Thanks for explaining.  I never would have figured that out.

Comment: This is because the spirit/purpose of the bounty program is _primarily_ to attract more attention and new answers to questions that have so far been lacking one or the other (or both), in the bounty offerer's opinion. Automatically giving a bounty to an answer that was already there doesn't reward new interest. People who start bounties with the intent of rewarding exceptional existing answers can still choose to assign them manually.